# MediaPipe object segmentation mask

Tags: python, image-segmentation, mediapipe

I am trying to detect objects in my images, mainly shoes. I am familiar that MediaPipe has the option to detect [3D objects](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/objectron.html) (it is only one mode which can take different models like: 'Shoe', 'Chair', 'Cup', 'Camera') but after running the algorithm, it only returns a bounding box around an object and I don't see any other outputs which can help me to get mask:
[image]

Is there any way to get a segmentation mask of the detected object? Something like that:
[image]